# Hide list from browser site/Lists/lisName

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-addin, custom-list

I am working with a sharepoint hosted app,
 I create some lists in my app,
is it possible to hide a list from browser? 
I mean, I do not want that a user can see a list with the url:

```
/site/Lists/listName
```

Thanks,Nk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically you can delete all of the views for the list and you will get a 404 if you try to access via the url. The list does technically still work if you are accessing it another way (like COM) though.

Comment: do you know why when i delete it in some lists, I can not deploy the solution?

Comment: I am deleting the view from the xml schema definition in vs12

Comment: no idea, sorry.